# Адаптивные вкладки

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Пишу небольшую адаптивную панель на Bootstrap с вкладками. Интересует как сделать значок "бургер" для экранов xs. Спасибо

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:font-size="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Карточка объекта</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Основная информация</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Оборудование</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Договоры и оплаты</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Контакты</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Коммерческие предложения и сметы</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">История</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Акты обследования</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab8" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">События графика</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
          <div class="jumbotron container-fluid" id="information">
              <h1>Карточка объекта</h1>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Адрес объекта</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">Орджоникидзе д.42</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Район</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">Московский</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Тип обслуживания</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                  Action
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Категория объекта</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">...</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Участок</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">...</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Инженер</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">...</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Ответственное лицо</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">...</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Персональный менеджер</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">...</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
          ...
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
          ...
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4">
          ...
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5">
          ...
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab6">
          ...
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab7">
          ...
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab8">
          ...
      </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Например:

```js
$.fn.responsiveTabs = function() {
  this.addClass('responsive-tabs');
  this.append($('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>'));
  
  this.on('click', 'li.active > a, span.glyphicon', function() {
    this.toggleClass('open');
  }.bind(this));

  this.on('click', 'li:not(.active) > a', function() {
    this.removeClass('open');
  }.bind(this));
};

$('.nav.nav-tabs').responsiveTabs();
```

```css
.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 42px;
  overflow: visible;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs span.glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  right: 22px;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs span.glyphicon.glyphicon-triangle-top {
  display: none;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li {
  display: none;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li:last-of-type > a {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li.active {
  display: block;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li.active a {
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs.open > li {
  display: block;
}
.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs.open > li a {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs.open > li:first-of-type a {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}
.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs.open > li:last-of-type a {
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  
  .responsive-tabs.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  
  .responsive-tabs.nav-tabs span.glyphicon {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li > a {
    margin-right: 4px;
  }
  
  .responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li.active a {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
  }
  
  .responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
  }
  
  .responsive-tabs.nav-tabs.open span.glyphicon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Основная информация</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Оборудование</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Договоры и оплаты</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Контакты</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Коммерческие предложения и сметы</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">История</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Акты обследования</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab8" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">События графика</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
          <div class="jumbotron container-fluid" id="information">
              <h1>Карточка объекта</h1>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Адрес объекта</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">Орджоникидзе д.42</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Район</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">Московский</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Тип обслуживания</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                  Action
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Категория объекта</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">...</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Участок</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">...</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Инженер</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">...</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Ответственное лицо</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">...</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Персональный менеджер</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">...</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
          ... Оборудование
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
          ... Договоры
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4">
          ... Контакты
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5">
          ... Коммерческие предложения
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab6">
          ... История
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab7">
          ... Акты
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab8">
          ... События
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Я вставил Ваш код в свой редактор, но результат тот же, в чем дело?

```js
$.fn.responsiveTabs = function() {
  this.addClass('responsive-tabs');
  this.append($('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>'));
  
  this.on('click', 'li.active > a, span.glyphicon', function() {
    this.toggleClass('open');
  }.bind(this));

  this.on('click', 'li:not(.active) > a', function() {
    this.removeClass('open');
  }.bind(this));
};

$('.nav.nav-tabs').responsiveTabs();
```

```css
.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 42px;
  overflow: visible;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs span.glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  right: 22px;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs span.glyphicon.glyphicon-triangle-top {
  display: none;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li {
  display: none;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li:last-of-type > a {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li.active {
  display: block;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li.active a {
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs.open > li {
  display: block;
}
.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs.open > li a {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs.open > li:first-of-type a {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}
.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs.open > li:last-of-type a {
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  
  .responsive-tabs.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  
  .responsive-tabs.nav-tabs span.glyphicon {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li > a {
    margin-right: 4px;
  }
  
  .responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li.active a {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
  }
  
  .responsive-tabs.nav-tabs > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
  }
  
  .responsive-tabs.nav-tabs.open span.glyphicon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Основная информация</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Оборудование</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Договоры и оплаты</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Контакты</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Коммерческие предложения и сметы</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">История</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Акты обследования</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab8" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">События графика</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
          <div class="jumbotron container-fluid" id="information">
              <h1>Карточка объекта</h1>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Адрес объекта</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">Орджоникидзе д.42</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Район</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">Московский</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Тип обслуживания</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                  Action
                              </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Категория объекта</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">...</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Участок</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">...</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Инженер</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">...</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Ответственное лицо</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">...</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">Персональный менеджер</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">...</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
          ... Оборудование
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
          ... Договоры
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4">
          ... Контакты
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5">
          ... Коммерческие предложения
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab6">
          ... История
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab7">
          ... Акты
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab8">
          ... События
      </div>
  </div>
```